# Add options in select with multiple attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

What is the best way to add and remove options in select element with multiple attribute , using jquery

I tried to add by the same way of adding in select without multiple attribute, but it is not working, the options added , but not appear in the select ul

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

The first is to set the selected item through the properties of the method, which can be used in dynamic languages such as php in the background to control the output as needed.

```js
< select  id =  "sel" >
    < option  value = "1" >1</ option >
    < option  value = "2"  selected = "selected" >2</ option >
    < option  value = "3" >3</ option >
</ select >
```

The second is to control the selected items through front-end js:

```js
< script  type = "text/javascript" >
function change(){
     document.getElementById("sel")[2].selected=true;
}
</ script >
< select  id =  "sel" >
    < option  value = "1" >1</ option >
    < option  value = "2" >2</ option >
    < option  value = "3" >3</ option >
</ select >
< input  type = "button"  value = "modify"  onclick = "change()"  />
```

The js code to get the text of the selected item of the tag is:

```js
var  val = document.all.Item.options[document.all.Item.selectedIndex].text
var  i=document.getElementById( 'sel' ).options[document.getElementById( 'sel' ).selectedIndex].value;
```

Some other tips for manipulating labels are as follows:

```js
1) Create select dynamically

function  createSelect(){
var  mySelect = document.createElement( "select" );
mySelect.id =  "mySelect" ;
document.body.appendChild(mySelect);
}

2)Add option

function  addOption(){
//Find an object based on its id，
var  obj=document.getElementById( 'mySelect' );
//Add an option
obj.add( new  Option( "text" , "value" ));
}

3)Delete all options

function  removeAll(){
var  obj=document.getElementById( 'mySelect' );
obj.options.length=0;
}

4)Delete option

function  removeOne(){
var  obj=document.getElementById( 'mySelect' );
//index,To remove the sequence number of an option, take the sequence number of the currently selected option here
var  index=obj.selectedIndex;
obj.options.remove(index);
}

5)get option value

var  obj=document.getElementById( 'mySelect' );
var  index=obj.selectedIndex;  //序号，取当前选中选项的序号
var  val = obj.options[index].value;

6)get option text

var  obj=document.getElementById( 'mySelect' );
var  index=obj.selectedIndex;  //Sequence number, which is the sequence number of the currently selected option
var  val = obj.options[index].text;

7)modify option

var  obj=document.getElementById( 'mySelect' );
var  index=obj.selectedIndex;  //Sequence number, which is the sequence number of the currently selected option
var  val = obj.options[index]= new  Option( "new text" , "new value" );

8)del select

function  removeSelect(){
var  mySelect = document.getElementById( "mySelect" );
mySelect.parentNode.removeChild(mySelect);
}1) Create select dynamically
```